# core data: [NSFetchedResultsController -fetchedObjects], will this method reflect object change?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

first I create a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a `NSFetchRequest` that fetches all object of entity "Entity".

and then I insert an new NSManagedObject A ,which is an instance of "Entity", and Edit B, which is also  an instance of "Entity".

then I call `NSArray *result = [fetchedResultsController -fetchedObjects]`, will A and B in result?

Throughout the project, I use **only one** NSManagedObjectContext.

if I do, what does this mean in its [Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

> fetchedObjects The results of the fetch.
>
> @property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *fetchedObjects Discussion The
>   value of the property is nil if performFetch: hasn’t been called.
>
> The results array only includes instances of the entity specified by
>   the fetch request (fetchRequest) and that match its predicate. (If the
>   fetch request has no predicate, then the results array includes all
>   instances of the entity specified by the fetch request.)
>
> The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in
>   the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the
>   persistent store. The returned array does not, however, update as
>   managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The meaning of the last sentence

> ... The returned array does not, however, update as managed objects are
>   inserted, modified, or deleted.

is (based on my experiments): If you store a reference to the fetched objects

```
NSArray *result = [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
```

then *this array referenced by* `result` will not update if objects are inserted, modified or deleted.
So the emphasis is on "the ***returned array*** does not ...".

But if you call

```
[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]
```

later again, the return value is a new list of objects, including the changes.

*More precisely:* If you have set a delegate, the FRC tracks changes to the managed object context and calls the FRC delegate functions. The delegate functions are not called immediately when objects are inserted/modified/deleted, but either

- when the context is saved explicitly, or
- when the change notifications are processed in the run loop.

As soon as `controllerDidChangeContent:` is called, a new call to `[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` returns the updated object list.

Comment: so if I call [fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] every time i need those object, they will be up to date, right? "The returned array" means the array which hold a reference to its return value but not "the array it will return", it is really confusing.

Comment: @user465191: Yes, `[fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` is up to date (after the delegate function has been called, not immediately after the insert). - I was also confused, but it really seems to mean that I have to call `fetchedObjects` again to get the changed objects. If I just store the reference to the return value then this referenced array does not change. - It is even difficult to describe what I mean!

Comment: @user465191: I have edited my answer and tried to make it more clear.

Comment: @user465191: Do you have more questions or do you think you can accept this answer?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't accept this answer now. It is after the controllerDidChangedContent: has been called, that the -fetchedObjects will return the result containing the new object. It is to say that if you insert the object and call -fetchedObjects in the same runloop pass, the result will not contain the newly-inserted object. Since the callback is async. Would you mind editing it and emphasize that the callback will be called in next runloop, calling -fetchedObjects instantly after inserting new object won't get the result containing new object. Thank you :)

Comment: @user465191: Thank you for the feedback!! I already meant it that way, but I have tried to improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

@Dwayne use `[fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges]` after your insert/delete/update if you want instant update on your delegate object, normally it is invoked at the end of the runloop.

Answer (score 1):

I just did an experiment on this as well. It seems that the fetchedObjects' count number got updated in this call:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath{
}
```

Dose this mean it's a incremental behavior each time it is called? And have the whole list ready when `controllerDidChangeContent:` is called since all changes have been executed?

@Maciek Czarnik Thanks for your explanation. However, if we can get the change each time `[fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges]` is not necessary to be called here anymore.

I hope I could have others confirm this bahavior, if possible.

Thanks.