# Core data fetching and getting an accurate object count

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm coding in iOS 6.1 and working with Core Data.

I have an entity; call it NextID.

When I establish my connection to Core data, the NextID.sqlite file is created when I do the addPersistentStoreWithType step.

At this point, I have an essentially empty database.

Then I create a fetch query and run it against the Entity and I get a fetchedResultsController back.

I count the objects held by the fetchedResultsController and get a zero, as I'd expect.

Then I create and initialize a new object for the NextID entity.

As a test, I count again with fetchedResultsController.count and get a zero again which is right, I think.

Then I save my context.

And then I test again with fetchedResultsController.count - and get a zero again.

Now I'm puzzled.

Then I read the following about the fetchedObjects:

"The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context, not their state in the persistent store. The returned array does not, however, update as managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted."

That seems like a contradictory statement to me.   "The results array reflects the in-memory state of managed objects in the controller’s managed object context" and "The returned array does not, however, update as managed objects are inserted, modified, or deleted." seem to me to be at cross purposes.

But regardless, I'm thinking that if I want to get an accurate count when I do a fetchedResultsController.count, then I need to save and then re-fetch before I ask for an up-to-date count.

I'm also thinking, because of what I've read elsewhere, that this will not be an expensive thing to do as doing a fetch operation is not the same as actually loading all the objects fetched into memory because those physical loads into memory only happen as they are needed.

Am I on the right track here and thinking about these things in a reasonable manner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [core data: \[NSFetchedResultsController -fetchedObjects\], will this method reflect object change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391934/core-data-nsfetchedresultscontroller-fetchedobjects-will-this-method-reflec)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to drive a wooden stake through this one's heart.  I think my question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391934/core-data-nsfetchedresultscontroller-fetchedobjects-will-this-method-reflec?rq=1).  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

use magical record if you are new to core data. its easy to integrate: 
here are tutorials: http://ablfx.com/blog/article/2

http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/#sthash.GNErDSr8.8VBBav02.dpbs

Comment: MagicalRecord uses the same NSFetchedResultsController as a "plain" Core Data app, so this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
What Gallymon said. Period.

What Gallymon said, and: the NSFetchedResultsController has delegate methods notifying you of new/updated/deleted items/sections. Those might either help you or confuse you even more (I am aiming for the first :) ).

Comment: The FRC delegate methods *are* mentioned in the link given by Gallymon  :-)