# Core data NSFetchedResultsController doesn't fetch automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a core data with NSBinaryStoreType persistent store which I init its managedObjectContext with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.

I have a NSFetchedResultsController property in my singleton class which I init like that:

```
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([CachedURLResponse class])];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"messageId" ascending:YES]];
        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
```

i.e , This objectContext has only entity of one type.

When I insert or delete objects my fetchObjects stays the same.
For instance if I print

```
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
```

before and after the following line:

```
MyEntity *myEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext];
```

The result remains the same.
Do I need to performFetch after every time I delete or insert an object?
Is there any way to auto-fetch them?

I know about the listen to the notification solution but not sure about what event I should listen to. Please let me know if this is the correct behaviour or if you have efficient solution

Comment: Have a look at the various answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391934/core-data-nsfetchedresultscontroller-fetchedobjects-will-this-method-reflec. You may have to call `processPendingChanges()`.

Comment: Also note that your context uses a private queue, which means all calls should be wrapped with either `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait`.  Only `performBlock` encapsulates a full user event, which means that calling `performBlock` will cause `processPendingChanges` to be called, but `performBlockAndWait` will not.